# iOS how to create development provisioning without having device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, apple-developer

I have created an app, I have paid account on Apple developer. I have created certificates and distribution provisioning, but Whenever I tried to make the development profile, it ask me for the device or list of device, see the image below:

[image]

This is a problem, I do not have any physical Apple mobile device. So I can not put UUID. So it looks like I can not complete my development profile provisioning vizard.

Please tell me how to create development provisioning profile here without having a real device??

Answer (score 2):

I think development provisioning profiles are only meant to test application app on real test iphone/ipad and you don't need one to test on Simulator and launch an app, distribution profiles are used when Creating an app iTunes connect and submit it, although I really recommend have an real iphone to test one, since some features are not available on simulator and sometimes it runs differently on real phone

Comment: I know the difference between distribution and development. Also I know that we must test on real device too. but please answer me related to context

Comment: Meaning you don’t need one to lunch an app on applestore

Comment: Thats not the appropriate answer

Comment: Why do you need one then so i can help?

Comment: I read  the chat,your question doesn’t have enough information,first you wont be able to run the app on your client phone without his uuid,but there sandbox tester in ituness connect meaning you can upload the app to ituness connect and let him downlod it from there,secondly when writing a question say your problem, so people know how write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add UDID of your real device iPhone or iPad in "Devices" section before creating development certificate.
You can use this UDID "".

Comment: the problem is "I do not have any physical Apple mobile device. "

Comment: use that i have sent you.

Comment: it is for my ipad.

Comment: is it safe for me? I mean will it ask for anything on your deice? any security barrier ?

Comment: Yes it is save. No security barrier.

Comment: workaround is that, you don't need to create provisioning profile if you are uploading app to app store. Development profile is only required if you want to run your app on real device. So just skip this step of creating development  provisioning profile.

Comment: but I want to create the IPA file and that must be development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173744/discussion-between-abilal17-and-android-teem).